# State Management when using ReactJS within a parent application

Tags: reactjs

This may or may not be a question with a straightforward answer. From poking around a bit, it seems like the answer to this may be 'Use Redux', but I'm curious to see what others have done.

I use React to introduce complex components in a parent Sharepoint application. This has unilaterally been a good thing for us, as it allows faster development with more modern behaviour on a small development team. However, I'm now running into situations in which I want multiple distinct react applications on the same page interacting with each other - preferably via the same state. Often it's just a question of passing one variable or function. From my initial research it seems like the straightforward answer is to use Redux as a sort of 'medium-term' store that holds information that needs to be shared between multiple components, while individual components continue using their own state happily.

I'm curious whether or not anyone else has run into this problem, and what your solutions to it have been. I would prefer to hold off on using redux for now, because I don't believe my state or application is complicated enough to warrant it.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just wrap everything in a higher level component that can manage state for the whole application?

Comment: @jered These react components are often in different parent containers on the page - I.e. they have different react roots. If you're familiar with Sharepoint, they're usually rendered in different web part zones.

Comment: you don't need complicated state to use redux. it's a tiny library and can be used for global / shared state with < .10 lines of code. https://medium.com/@benevolentNinja/minimal-redux-setup-e6a10fcbcb68

Comment: I agree with jered and azium - move your state up and use redux. This is an opinion, but redux is so lightweight and predictable that for anything beyond a PoC I would recommend using it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments - I'll start working in redux.